# ways to check overflow when converting Array{Int64} to Array{Int32}

Tags: julia

is there any way to check overflow when converting an Array{Int64} to Array{Int32}?

```
julia> x = [0,100,2^50]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
                0
              100
 1125899906842624

julia> int32(x)
3-element Array{Int32,1}:
   0
 100
   0
```

I know one naive way is to check `all(typemin(Int32) .< x .< typemax(Int32))`. But I am looking for a more efficient method.

---

Edit:

I tried to compare a devectozied but less elegant function `g`.

```
f(x::Array{Int64, 1}) = all(typemin(Int32) .< x .< typemax(Int32))
function g(x::Array{Int64, 1})
    a = typemin(Int32)
    b = typemax(Int32)
    for z in x
        if !(a<z<b)
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end
x = convert(Array, (2^31-10000):(2^31));
@time for i in 1:1000; f(x); end
@time for i in 1:1000; g(x); end
```

It turns out that `g` uses less memory and hence much faster than `f`:

```
julia> @time for i in 1:1000; f(x); end
elapsed time: 0.046384046 seconds (13186456 bytes allocated)

julia> @time for i in 1:1000; g(x); end
elapsed time: 0.015128743 seconds (7824 bytes allocated)
```

Comment: Interestingly, checking instead of truncation is now the default behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure how you could be more efficient than that, to be honest.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski, you mean in v0.4?

Comment: Yes, it's changed in 0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the direct examination method to be faster.  Like you discovered above, memory usage is likely the reason. So in this case, you can exchange convenience for run speed and achieve better performance.

### assumption

You're only concerned with if there will be an error if  *Array{Int64}* when converted to an *Array{Int32}*.  That obviously is the case when that number is > 2^32.

```
julia> int32(2^42)
0
```

but trying to represent anything greater than 2^31 - 1 also a problem because of the use of 2's complement.

```
julia> x = 2^31 - 1
2147483647

julia> int32(x) == x
true

julia> y = 2^31
2147483648

julia> int32(y) == y
false
```

### comparison

The 2 functions I used for comparison were

```
function check1(x) 
   all(typemin(Int32) .< x .< typemax(Int32))
end

function check2(x)
   ok = true;
   const min = -2^31
   const max = 2^31 - 1;

   for i = 1:length(x)
      v = x[i]
      if v > max || v < min 
         ok = false;
         break;
      end
   end
   ok
end
```

### results

check2 will be faster because it will stop immediately as soon as 1 bad value is found, but is faster even under the worst conditions

```
julia> z = convert(Array{Int64},ones(10000));


julia> @time for i = 1:1000 check2(z) end
elapsed time: 0.008574832 seconds (0 bytes allocated)


julia> @time for i = 1:1000 check1(z) end
elapsed time: 0.036393418 seconds (13184000 bytes allocated)
```

#### embellished

if the **@inbounds** macro is used, the speed is consistently increased by approximately 60%

```
   @inbounds v = x[i]
```

new results

```
julia> @time for i = 1:1000 check2(z) end
elapsed time: 0.005379673 seconds (0 bytes allocated)
```

### verification

While verifying the correctness, I stumbled on this

```
julia> u = [ 2^31 - 2; 2^31 - 1; 2^31 ]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2147483646
 2147483647
 2147483648


julia> for n in u println(check1([n])) end
true
false
false

julia> for n in u println(check2([n])) end
true
true
false
```

It looks like check1 is incorrect, 2^31 - 1 can be represented by a 32 bit integer.  Instead check1 should use **<=**.

```
function check1(x) 
   all(typemin(Int32) .<= x .<= typemax(Int32))
end
```

Comment: thx for the input; I think `for v in x` should be even faster. +1

Comment: @RandyLai I tried that too, but it prevents the use of the **`@simd`** macro which I also tried.  In this case **`@simd`** does not speed things up so I discarded it but when I did that I did not revert back to **for ... in**.  If you try it and find it helps, msg back and I'll update.